# How to append new data to an existing JSON array(swiftyJSON)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I have an array of SwiftyJson data that I have declared and filled it with data .The code I'm using to fill the hoge array is this : `self.hoge = JSON(data: data!)`

but I need to append new swiftyJSON data to this hoge array  .I noticed hoge array doesn't have append property .  How should I do that?

Thanks

Comment: @adnan I have declared hoge like this ` var hoge:JSON = []` and as soon as I changed it's type to NSMutableArray I got error that says JSON is not convertible to NSMutableArray . What I have done wrong?Thanks

Comment: I agree, I think swiftyjson could have more user friendly documentation :>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SwiftyJSON does not have `append` or `extend` functionality.

You can:

```
self.hoge = JSON(self.hoge.arrayObject! + JSON(data: newData).arrayObject!)
```

But I recommend to declare `self.hoge` as `[JSON]`

```
var hoge:[JSON] = []

func readMoreData() {

    let newData: NSData = ...

    if let newArray = JSON(data:newData).array {
        self.hoge += newArray
    }
}
```

Comment: .Thanks it works fine and add new data to hoge. the only problem left is that I used to return datas from hoge like this `self.hoge[indexPath.row]["cars"]["pic_name"]` but now I got error that says cannot index empty buffer . How should I return data now? Thanks again

Comment: Tried it, but += operator does not seem to work with JSON objects. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 9):

### Swift 2-4

Another solution, using `Extension`

```
extension JSON{
    mutating func appendIfArray(json:JSON){
        if var arr = self.array{
            arr.append(json)
            self = JSON(arr);
        }
    }
    
    mutating func appendIfDictionary(key:String,json:JSON){
        if var dict = self.dictionary{
            dict[key] = json;
            self = JSON(dict);
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var myJSON: JSON = [
    "myDictionary": [String:AnyObject](),
    "myArray" : [1,2,3,4]
]

myJSON["myDictionary"].appendIfDictionary(key:"A", json: JSON(["key1":"value1"]))
myJSON["myDictionary"].appendIfDictionary(key: "B", json: JSON(["key2":"value2"]))
myJSON["myArray"].appendIfArray(json: JSON(5))
```

print:

```
{
  "myArray" : [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  "myDictionary" : {
    "B" : {
      "key2" : "value2"
    },
    "A" : {
      "key1" : "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but it's not saving...." was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available." error appeared and after closing the app, nothing changes

Comment: @DumitruRogojinaru I didn't test that on swift 3 so I guess something was changed, I'll update my answer in the next few days

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `merge` function for this.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#merging

```
var array: JSON = [1, 2, 3]
array = try! array.merged(with: [4])
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let jsonNewJSON:JSON = JSON(newData)
var arr:[JSON]=jsonOBJ.arrayValue
arr.append(jsonNewJSON)
var combinedOBJ = JSON(arr)
```

I used the above code to append to a swiftyjson array . I first converted the new data to a JSON object. Then I got the array of the existing JSON and append the new JSON. I converted the array back to a JSON object. Admit-ably not great code, but I did not need performance here and it got the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Declare you main JSON Array as :

```
var data:[JSON] = []
```

If the data source is any other object (like realm) loop over it using for loop
But if the data source is another JSON Array perform :

```
func setData(){
        data = []
        if let items = sourceData.array {
            for item in items {
              data.append(item)
            }
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.hoge` should be a Swift Array (which is mutable if declared as var) or casted to a NSMutableArray. If it is of Array type use append. If casted to an NSMutableArray use `self.hoge.addObject(yourObject)`.

Comment: I have declared hoge like this var hoge:JSON = [] .How should I modified that?I tied to convert it to NSMutableArray which gave me an error that JSON is not convertible to NSMutableArray . Could you help me with that Please?Thanks

Comment: declare it as `hoge = [JSON]()`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a dictionary to the JSON data in my project. I added to [Daniel Krom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4126633/daniel-krom)'s answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36984699/2185588):

```
import SwiftyJSON

extension JSON {
    
    mutating func appendIfKeyValuePair(key: String, value: Any){
        if var dict = self.dictionaryObject {
            dict[key] = value
            self = JSON(dict)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data: JSON = []

data.appendIfKeyValuePair(key: "myKey", value: "myValue")
```